# commonly associated letters with each other in the column - R

Tags: r

I am having following dateset and I am looking for help BY using R I want to find out commonly associated letters with each other in the names column:

```
df = data.frame(
  id = 1:6,
  names = c('A', 'A, B', 'P, C','C, A, B', 'B, C', 'A, C'))
```

I am trying to identify the letters commonly associated with each other.

Thank you for instance I want to know many times A is associated with B or A is associated with B & C.

I WANT TO GET RESULT FOR COMMONLY ASSOCIATED OR CORRELATION BETWEEN EACH LETTER with in same column.

Comment: Can you show the expected output.  When you say commonly associated, is it occuring more than once?

Comment: Yeah, I did not understand either what you are referring as commonly associated.

Comment: I am trying to identify the letters commonly associated with each other
Thank you
for instance I want to know many times  A is associated with B or A is associated with B & C
i WANT TO GET RESULT FOR COMMONLY ASSOCIATED OR CORRELATION BETWEEN EACH LETTER with in same column

Comment: So... `{A, A} = AA+1; {B, P} = BP+1; {C, C} = CC+1; {A, B} = AB+1, {B, C} = BC+1 {A,C} = AC+1?`